# Javascript function to try element in array if one was not found

Tags: javascript

I have the following js function in a React App that gets the county/district

This works to get `administrative_area_level_2`.

```
    export const getDistrict = place => {
  var filtered_array = place.address_components.filter(function(address_component)
  {
    return address_component.types
  return district
}
```

How to modify the above function to efficiently check for `administrative_2` first and then if not present get `administrative_1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter` doesn't make much sense here, because you don't need to create an intermediate array, you just need to find a value. You might use `.find` to return a `administrative_area_level_2`, if found, else an `administrative_area_level_1`, else `unknown`:

```
export const getDistrict = ({ address_components }) => {
  const lvl2 = address_components.find(({ types }) => types.includes('administrative_area_level_2'));
  if (lvl2) return lvl2.long_name;
  const lvl1 = address_components.find(({ types }) => types.includes('administrative_area_level_1'));
  return lvl1 ? lvl1.long_name : 'Unknown';
};
```

Or, to keep your code more DRY, abstract the `.find` and `long_name` access into a separate function:

```
const makeFindType = arr => levelNum => {
  const found = arr.find(({ types }) => types.includes('administrative_area_level_' + levelNum));
  if (found) return found.long_name;
};

export const getDistrict = ({ address_components }) => {
  const findType = makeFindType(address_components);
  return findType('2') || findType('1') || 'Unknown';
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add the logic in the method to check first in administrative_area_level_1, if found return and stop the execution, If not continue the search in administrative_area_level_2